# React native debugger - how to save breakpoints when refresh app

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I set breakpoint using the "Sources" tab within the Chrome debugging console (within React Native Debugger)....but when I double-press R to refresh app the breakpoints dissapear.
Anyone know how to persist breakpoints on refresh?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the debugger removes the breakpoints every time you refresh the app, a workaround could be adding in the code: `debugger;` in the line you want to put the breakpoint.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this use case? How and where do I put that? It doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Literally put line `debugger;` in your code and debugger will stop there. But notice two Gs.